# Can`t get value of member of derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have:

```
VirtualClass : public QObject
{
public:
    int m_number;
}

DerivedClass : public VirtualClass 
{
public:
    DerivedClass(int number) : m_number(number) {};
    int m_number;
    // some content goes here..
}
```

client code:

```
f(VirtualClass* instance)
{
std::cout << instance->m_number;
}

DerivedClass der(100);
```

I want `f(der)` to **return m_number that relates to DerivedClass** , but *I get m_number of VirtualClass*.
What I am doing wrong?!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `int m_number;` from the `DerivedClass`. Otherwise you have to different `m_number` members. One is from `VirtualClass` and other is from `DerivedClass`.

When you add `int m_number;` in the `DerivedClass` you hide `m_number;` of `VirtualClass`

Here is an example how it works:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    int a; //another a
};

int main()
{
    Bar *f = new Bar();
    f->a = 10; //Bar::a

    Foo *b = f;
    b->a = 20; //Foo::a

    cout << f->a << endl; //prints 10
    cout << b->a << endl; //prints 20
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you. I have followed your advise. Also I removed member initializer syntax when calling constructor of derived class:
replaced class(int number):m_number(number){}; with simple 
class (int number){m_number = number}, otherwise compilation fails

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `int m_number;` twice. You should only declare it once.

Answer (score 2):

spin_eight:
You can keep your initializer list, if you want to by providing an appropriate constructor on the VirtualClass, and calling it from the derived initializer list, like so:

```
VirtualClass : public QObject 
{ 
 public: 
 VirtualClass(int number) : m_number(number) { }
 int m_number; 
}

DerivedClass : public VirtualClass
{
 public: 
 DerivedClass(int number) : VirtualClass(number) {}; 
 // some content goes here.. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks better than: simple class (int number){m_number = number}
And even works faster